# how do i validate date input in dd-mon-yyyy format in asp.net regularExpressionValidator?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, validation

I really neeed dd-mon-yy format because my oracle database accepts dates in this format.

Can I validate like that in RegularExpressionValidator like that?

And also, do I have to convert the textbox value to oracle data time format, when using nhibernate?

thanks a lot for help;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For two digits for the year try:

```
^([012]?\d|3[01])-([Jj][Aa][Nn]|[Ff][Ee][Bb]|[Mm][Aa][Rr]|[Aa][Pp][Rr]|[Mm][Aa][Yy]|[Jj][Uu][Nn]|[Jj][Uu][Ll]|[Aa][Uu][Gg]|[Ss][Ee][Pp]|[Oo][Cc][Tt]|[Nn][Oo][Vv]|[Dd][Ee][Cc])-\d\d$
```

With four digits for the year:

```
^([012]?\d|3[01])-([Jj][Aa][Nn]|[Ff][Ee][Bb]|[Mm][Aa][Rr]|[Aa][Pp][Rr]|[Mm][Aa][Yy]|[Jj][Uu][Nn]|[Jj][Uu][Ll]|[Aa][Uu][Gg]|[Ss][Ee][Pp]|[Oo][Cc][Tt]|[Nn][Oo][Vv]|[Dd][Ee][Cc])-(19|20)\d\d$
```

Those expressions mean:

- 0 or 1 or 2 followed by a number, or 3 plus 0 or 1
- next a dash
- For the month it 'tries' all the combinations of JAN, JAn, Jan, jan, etc... for all the twelve months
- next a dash
- Finally it expects two digits for 'yyyy' version or 19 or 20 followed by two digits for 'yy' version

Answer (score 3):

try

`Regx.ValidationExpression=@"^(([1-9])|(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\-((0[1-9])
|([1-31]))\-((\d{2})|(\d{4}))$";`

or

you can try this custom validator instead

protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{

DateTime result;

if (!DateTime.TryParse(args.Value, out result))

{

args.IsValid = false;

return;

} else args.IsValid = true;

}

Answer (score 2):

Is it necessary to force the user to enter the data in the format proscribed by the Oracle database?  As long as the user enters a valid date, you can parse the input into a DateTime object and then call ToString("dd-MMMM-yy") to produce a representation of the date in the format required by the database.  This gives you the freedom to provide more a user-friendly means of collecting input from the user e.g. a date/time picker type control.